# Commit A Different Animation(s) While Another Animation is ending

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to create a 'wave' effect of `UIView` animations.

I have numerous layers to animate. I'm currently animating them with `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`

I have the views displayed in a stack so for example:

```
-------------------------------
|           VIEW 1            |
-------------------------------
|           VIEW 2            |
-------------------------------
|           VIEW 3            |
-------------------------------
|           VIEW 4            |
-------------------------------
|           VIEW 5            |
-------------------------------
|           VIEW 6            |
-------------------------------
```

This is important to know because `UIView` transitions are not what I'm going after.

I can easily animate them and concurrently activate the next view animation in the completion block of the previous view. So this is how it's currently set up:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{ 
    self.view1.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{
      self.view2.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           etc...
    }];
}];
```

What i would like to do, instead of concurrently activating the next view animation I would like it to activate *while* the previous views animation is ending. So say, the last half of time in the animation process, start the next views animation to get a wave effect. None of the `UIViewAnimationOptions` match my criteria, and I've also researched the developer forums for a similar goal, with no results.

What I have tried:

The workaround that I've tried is adding a delay to the next `UIView` animations inside the animations block as opposed to the completion block, but I feel this isn't a healthy take on the matter. Ex:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{
    //Other animations...
    self.view1.alpha = 1.0f
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0.2f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        self.view2.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         //repeat..     
    }];
}];
```

As you can see my work around, well, works. But as I stated above, it doesn't feel an iota of healthy. What am I missing?

---

**EDIT**

I inevitably went the route of using `UIViewAnimationOptions` by delaying and autoreversing the durations:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = 3.0;
NSTimeInterval delay = 0.5f;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0f options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
    self.view1.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
    self.view2.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:delay*2 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
    self.view3.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CALayer` animation instead of `UIView` animation to achieve this. Just configure the begin time, duration and the animation on each view's layer. Here is a quick Swift example:

```
for (var i, v) in enumerate(views) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"opacity")
    animation.toValue = 0.0
    animation.duration = 0.4
    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.2 * i
    v.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "wave")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, CABasicAnimations didn't work with my project. For some reason I could only get them to animate sequentially, and had problems with `animationDidStop:` callbacks. So I just tidied up my code a little bit and utilized `UIViewAnimationOptions`